# Just change all files to writable from root , how to reverse this?

Tags: linux

I accidentally did this:

```
chmod -R 777 /
```

I suppose to do this:

```
chmod -R 777 ./
```

I feel really bad now. How can I reverse this??

Comment: Don't feel bad.  It'd have been worse if you did `sudo chmod -R -x /`.

Comment: There are two kinds of people in the world. Those who have destroyed a file system running as root -- and those who haven't done it ***yet.***  Don't run as root ;)

Comment: At least now I feel no sleepy no more. Again, GOD!

Comment: Heh, I did that something like that once and then the automatic shutdown procedure in Ubuntu when my laptop battery was low would do something along the lines of "Battery low, shutting down. Error: Insufficient Permissions", and my laptop would stay on until I shut it down manually or it literally drained the entire battery.

Comment: @Jusfeel, You can reverse this but I think before doing this you need to know what is default permission. Each user has a default set of permissions which apply to all files created by that user, unless the software explicitly sets something else. This is often called the 'umask', after the command used to change it. It is either inherited from the login process, or set in the .cshrc or .login file which configures an individual account, or it can be run manually. Typically the default configuration is equivalent to typing 'umask 22'.  So run the command chmod again with the default permission

Comment: @Gourabp -- He lost all of the elevated privilege permissions too. Things like `login`, `sudo`, `su` and a good number of others have the permissions of `1755`.  A handful of files have to have `0600` or the associated services won't run.

Comment: To report, first, SSH was out. No remote access - The key is too open. MySQL cannot load my.cnf because it's writable. I fixed these 2 cases by changing back permissions. Anything else worth checking?

Comment: See [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13031/11750).

Comment: `chmod -R 777 ./` would have been wrong too. It is extremely rare to need to set files to mode 777. I can't think of ever needing to set a whole directory hierarchy to mode 777. `chmod -R a+rx .` or `chmod -R u+w .` are common. `chmod -R 777 .` was a mistake from the start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

short version: You can't.
Unless you have a backup or similar which lists the permissions of all your files, you don't know what the files need to be.

Comment: God. Won't CentOS provide some tools to do permissions...RESET or some sort?

Comment: Sorry, no, there isn't.

Comment: `for allpkg in $(rpm -qa); do rpm --setperms $allpkg; done` resets file permissions for all installed packages. This does not help with user files...

Comment: @Jusfeel There is a tool to reset permissions. It's called **restoring from a backup**. If you want to avoid some data copying, it's possible to restore the permissions while leaving the data in place. How to do that depends on what backup tool you used.